# using direct2d and white pixels turn into gray

Tags: c++, colors, rendering, direct2d

I'm using c++ and direct2d to create a windows application.
I'm trying to draw rectangles with the DrawRectangle function.
The problem is that when I'm drawing a white rectangle on a dark surface it turns gray even though alpha is set to 1.0f. It also happens when I draw black on a light surface.
I want the color on the screen to be exactly what I entered. How do I do that?

```
void Graphics::DrawRect(RECT rect, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    m_Brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b, a));
    m_RenderTarget->DrawRectangle(D2D1::Rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom), m_Brush);
}
```

this is my brush:

```
m_RenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(0, 0, 0, 0), &m_Brush);
```

and this is the function call:

```
graphics->DrawRect(currentRenderRect, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

EDIT
this is my entire graphics class:

.h

```
class Graphics
{
public:
    Graphics();
    ~Graphics();

    bool Initialize(HWND windowHandle);

    void BeginDraw() { m_RenderTarget->BeginDraw(); }
    void EndDraw()   { m_RenderTarget->EndDraw();   }

    void ClearScreen(float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void DrawCircle(float x, float y, float radius, float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void DrawLine(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void DrawRect(RECT rect, float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void DrawDashRect(RECT rect, float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void DrawFilledRect(RECT rect, float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void DrawBitmap(ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap);
    void DrawBitmap(ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap, RECT rect);

    ID2D1Bitmap* CreateBitmap(HBITMAP bitmap);

private:

    ID2D1Factory*           m_Factory;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*  m_RenderTarget;
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush*   m_Brush;
    ID2D1StrokeStyle*       m_DashStrokeStyle;

    int m_WindowWidth;
    int m_WindowHeight;
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "Graphics.h"

Graphics::Graphics()
{
    m_Factory         = NULL;
    m_RenderTarget    = NULL;
    m_Brush           = NULL;
    m_WhiteBrush      = NULL;
    m_DashStrokeStyle = NULL;
}

Graphics::~Graphics()
{
    if (m_Factory)
        m_Factory->Release();

    if (m_RenderTarget)
        m_RenderTarget->Release();

    if (m_Brush)
        m_Brush->Release();

    if (m_WhiteBrush)
        m_WhiteBrush->Release();

    if (m_DashStrokeStyle)
        m_DashStrokeStyle->Release();
}

bool Graphics::Initialize(HWND windowHandle)
{
    HRESULT res;
        
    res = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &m_Factory);

    if (res != S_OK)
        return false;

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(windowHandle, &rect);

    m_WindowWidth   = rect.right - rect.left;
    m_WindowHeight  = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    res = m_Factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(windowHandle, D2D1::SizeU(m_WindowWidth, m_WindowHeight)),
        &m_RenderTarget);

    if (res != S_OK)
        return false;

    m_RenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(0, 0, 0, 0), &m_Brush);

    if (res != S_OK)
        return false;

    m_RenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White), &m_WhiteBrush);

    if (res != S_OK)
        return false;

    float dashes[] = { 3, 3 };

    res = m_Factory->CreateStrokeStyle(
        D2D1::StrokeStyleProperties(
            D2D1_CAP_STYLE_FLAT,
            D2D1_CAP_STYLE_FLAT,
            D2D1_CAP_STYLE_ROUND,
            D2D1_LINE_JOIN_MITER,
            10.0f,
            D2D1_DASH_STYLE_CUSTOM,
            0.0f),
        dashes,
        ARRAYSIZE(dashes),
        &m_DashStrokeStyle
    );

    if (res != S_OK)
        return false;
}

void Graphics::ClearScreen(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    m_RenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b, a));
}

void Graphics::DrawCircle(float x, float y, float radius, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    m_Brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b, a));
    m_RenderTarget->DrawEllipse(D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(x, y), radius, radius), m_Brush);
}

void Graphics::DrawLine(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    m_Brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b, a));
    m_RenderTarget->DrawLine(D2D1::Point2F(x0, y0), D2D1::Point2F(x1, y1), m_Brush);
}

void Graphics::DrawRect(RECT rect, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    m_Brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b, a));
    m_RenderTarget->DrawRectangle(D2D1::Rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom), m_Brush);
}

void Graphics::DrawDashRect(RECT rect, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    m_Brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b, a));
    m_RenderTarget->DrawRectangle(D2D1::Rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom), m_Brush, 1.0f, m_DashStrokeStyle);
}


void Graphics::DrawFilledRect(RECT rect, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    m_Brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b, a));
    m_RenderTarget->FillRectangle(D2D1::Rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom), m_Brush);
}

void Graphics::DrawBitmap(ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap)
{
    m_RenderTarget->DrawBitmap(bitmap, D2D1::Rect(0, 0, m_WindowWidth, m_WindowHeight), 1.0f, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, NULL);
}

void Graphics::DrawBitmap(ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap, RECT rect)
{
    m_RenderTarget->DrawBitmap(bitmap, D2D1::Rect(rect.left + 1, rect.top + 1, rect.right - 1, rect.bottom - 1), 1.0f, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, D2D1::Rect(rect.left + 1, rect.top + 1, rect.right - 1, rect.bottom - 1));
}

ID2D1Bitmap* Graphics::CreateBitmap(HBITMAP bitmap)
{
    BITMAP bmpSizeInfo;

    GetObject(bitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpSizeInfo);

    BITMAPINFO bmpData;

    memset(&bmpData, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bmpData.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmpData.bmiHeader);
    bmpData.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bmpSizeInfo.bmHeight;
    bmpData.bmiHeader.biWidth = bmpSizeInfo.bmWidth;
    bmpData.bmiHeader.biPlanes = bmpSizeInfo.bmPlanes;
    bmpData.bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmpSizeInfo.bmBitsPixel;

    char* pBuff = new char[bmpSizeInfo.bmWidth * bmpSizeInfo.bmHeight * 4];

    HDC hDc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
    GetDIBits(hDc, bitmap, 0, bmpSizeInfo.bmHeight, (void*)pBuff, &bmpData, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES bmpPorp;

    bmpPorp.dpiX = 0.0f;
    bmpPorp.dpiY = 0.0f;
    bmpPorp.pixelFormat.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    bmpPorp.pixelFormat.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE;

    ID2D1Bitmap* pBmpFromH;

    D2D1_SIZE_U bmpSize = { bmpSizeInfo.bmWidth, bmpSizeInfo.bmHeight };

    m_RenderTarget->CreateBitmap(bmpSize, pBuff, 4 * bmpSizeInfo.bmWidth, bmpPorp, &pBmpFromH);

    delete[] pBuff;

    return pBmpFromH;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: DrawRectangle misses arguments, etc. it can be due to something else in your code, please post a fully reproducing project.

Comment: The reason might be that you're drawing with what you think as exact coordinates, like (0,0,10,10), and you expect rectangle to fully cover pixel 0,0. Try instead to shift by 0.5f, like (0.5f,0.5f,10.5f,10.5f).